# Trouble with uploading multiple uploaded files

Tags: php, upload

So I have a script which allows to files to get uploaded at once:

```
<input style = "width: 90px;" name="book-image" type="file" id="image" value = "Upload">
<input style = "width: 90px;" name="book-preview" type="file" id="book" value = "Upload">
```

Here is the receiving script: if the image exists, it tests if the preview (pdf) exists and then runs 2 functions to upload each image and pdf.

```
if(file_exists($_FILES['book-image']['tmp_name']) || is_uploaded_file($_FILES['book-image']['tmp_name'])) {
        //If there is a preview or non-free book
        if((file_exists($_FILES['book-preview']['tmp_name']) || is_uploaded_file($_FILES['book-preview']['tmp_name']))) {
            //valid - upload image, preview and add book 
            if($image = uploadBookImage() && $pdf = uploadPreviewPdf()) {
                $newValues['imagefilename'] = $image;
                $newValues['previewfile'] = $pdf;
                if($qc->insertBook($newValues)) {
                    $message = "Added Book!";
                } else{
                    $error .= "Couldn't add book";
                }
            }
        }
}
```

$qc->insertBook($values); adds the values to the database.

Here are the uploader functions:

```
function uploadBookImage() {
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$gay = explode(".", $_FILES['book-image']['name']);
$extension = end($gay);
$target_path = "../images/books/";
$filename = $_FILES["book-image"]["name"];
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['book-image']['name']); 
if ((($_FILES["book-image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["book-image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["book-image"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["book-image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["book-image"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
    if (file_exists($target_path)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['book-image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            echo $filename;
            return $filename;
        }
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
}//function

function uploadPreviewPdf() {
     $allowedExts = array("pdf");
     $gay = explode(".", $_FILES['book-preview']['name']);
     $extension = end($gay);
     $target_path = '../previews/';
     $filename = $_FILES['book-preview']['name'];
     $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['book-preview']['name']);   
     if((($_FILES['book-preview']['type'] == 'application/pdf'))
         && ($_FILES['book-preview']['size'] < 6000000)
         && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
         if(file_exists($target_path)) {
           return false;
         } else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['book-preview']['tmp_name'],    $target_path)) {
            return $filename;
        }
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

**The Problem: When I upload both, It adds the value 1 for the image name, and the filename  for the pdf - to the database. However if I upload only the image it add the image name into the database**

**Output of var dump when uploading image: outputs image file name and 
Output of var dump when uploading image and pdf: outputs image file name**

I have no idea why. Please help.

Comment: What is `var_dump($_FILES)` in both cases?

Comment: Checking Now. Stay tuned. Desperate Lol.

Comment: Yes debugging can suck. Just take a short break and with fresh eyes and step-by-step troubleshooting it's often possible quick then.

Comment: Ok here are the test results! 
Uploading just an image: var dump returned just the image name (As I expected). 
Uploading the image and the pdf, var dump returned just the image again. But I looked in both directories of upload, and both files were there. Weird huh.

Comment: You should add the output of the var_dumps to your question. Otherwise it is hard to say if that is weird at all ;)

Comment: Done, bit messy but I'm in a hurry. Do you think it could be the:
if($image = uploadBookImage() && $pdf = uploadPreviewPdf()) {
should that be: 
if ($image = uploadBookImage()) {
    if($pdf = uploadPreviewPdf()) {
    }
}
I guess I'll try that.

Comment: Well you didn't add the `var_dump` output to your question. Probably your problem is to be in a hurry. That often prevents one from solving technical issues. I highly suggest you slow down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

It was the:

```
if($image = uploadBookImage() && $pdf = uploadPreviewPdf()) {
     $newValues['imagefilename'] = $image;
     $newValues['previewfile'] = $pdf;
}
```

It needed to be

```
if($image = uploadBookImage()) {
    $newValues['imagefilename'] = $image;
    if($pdf = uploadPreviewPdf()){         
         $newValues['previewfile'] = $pdf;
    }
}
```

Not sure why though. Can anyone explain why? My only guess would be that it doesn't have time to complete both checks so quickly?